# proper override checkout/block/cart/item/renderer.php

Tags: magento2

i need to add a new function to it and can modify core to add it and know that's not the right way. Can't find anything online that would give me a hint on how either.

Comment: try below added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Magento 2 override block class using di.xml
> Create file : [Vendor][Module]\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Rewrite\Cart\Item\Renderer" />
</config>
```

> Create class [Vendor][Module]\Block\Rewrite\Rewrite\Cart\Item\Renderer to override Magento block

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Rewrite\Cart\Item;

class Renderer extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer
{

    protected function getABC()
    {
        //add code
    }
}
```